# Keepalived Virtual IP is not able to ping from other VM

Tags: networking, openstack

I am running HA Proxy and Keepalived in Openstack VMs. (VM1-192.168.10.1, VM2 - 192.168.10.2). Keepalived is configured with VIP 192.168.10.50/24. VIP got assigned to VM1. I logged in to VM2 and tried pinging VM1's ip - working, when I try to ping VIP, I am getting "Destination Host Unreachable" error. Below is my Keepalived config file content.

```
global_defs {
    router_id LVS_DEVEL
    enable_script_security
}
vrrp_script check_apiserver {
    script "/etc/keepalived/check_apiserver.sh"
    interval 3
    weight -2
    fall 3
    rise 2
}
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 100
    priority 100
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass password
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.10.50/24
    }
    track_script {
        check_apiserver
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me on this?